# R - Como converter a codificação de todas as colunas de um data.table?

Tags: r, conversão, data.rable-r

Olá !

Já olhei a documentação do `data.table()` , mas ainda não consegui entender completamente.

Como seria essa função, para um dt ?

```r
for(i in 1:ncol(df1))
{

    df1[,i] <- df1[,i] %>% iconv(from = 'UTF-8', to = 'latin1')

}
```

Em um data.frame ela converte todas as colunas de UTF-8 para latin1.

Alguma forma mais simples ?

Obrigado!

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil ler os dados com a função `fread()` que permite de definir a codificação: `fread('file.txt, encoding = "latin1")`?

Comment: Sim ! mas acontece que importei uma base muito grande e só agora me atentei pro encoding. Para importar de novo irá demorar. Aí gostaria de uma outra saída.

Comment: Encontrei essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492969/apply-encoding-to-entire-data-table

Comment: Talvez `dt[, lapply(.SD, iconv, from = 'UTF-8', to = 'latin1')]`.